# String Bus [][][][]... or DataBase or somthing else ... what to choose for my data?

Tags: android, arrays, database

I want to do "bus plan app". I have a question to you:
What way will be better to code plan?
in array, in data base, other way?
I don't want come to death end and go back to start point again.
I was thinking about array:
String bus_stop [one element - bus nr.]  [arrive time] [departure time].
Where arrive time is mostly the same what departure time, and sometimes arrive time have 8 elements and other time have 38 (the same departure time). I think plan for next year is going to change, so important for me is to easy new plan update.
I was never before use database, but it's seem easy way to store and show data to user.
So please help.

Comment: Go for database as they will provide better flexibility for any future changes. Not sure how you will implement the same using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *defiantly* use a **database**, using alternative approaches such as storing data in RAM or XML files can be quite RAM intensive and could slow down your app. as @SMR said, using a database would give you much greater flexibility and integration with other services (API's perhaps?)

As you stated you have never covered databases before I'll share a link to a tutorial on how to get started with **SQLite** on Android, Its the simplest way to integrate a database (and maintainable persistent storage) from within your android application. Link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm